# How is the contract initialized in truffle tests in solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";
contract TestAdoption {

    **Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());**

    function testGetAdoptorAddressByPetId() public{
        address expected = this;
        address[16] memory adoptors = adoption.getAdoptors();
        Assert.equal(adoptors[8], expected, "Owner of pet Id 8 should be recorded");
    }

}
```

Can any one explain how the contract instance is created from the address in truffle framework?
Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test contract `TestAdoption` is deployed automatically by the Truffle test framework, your contract `Adoption` are deployed in the migration scripts.

This line

```
Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());
```

does not create a new contract but instead assign to the `adoption` variable the address deployed by the migrations scripts (the deployed addresses are stored inside the `DeployedAddresses` contract)

For more information about Truffle Solidity Test check their [documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand that part where deployed addresses are stored in DepoyledAddresses.sol and retreived using DepoyledAddresses.<contract Name>().

Why is the address of a deployed contract  wrapped in contract name "Adoption(address)". What is the internal working of this statement. Is what I find it difficult to understand.

Comment: The function `DeployedAddresses.Adoption()` returns a value of type `address`, in solidity you cannot assign it directly to a variable of type `Adoption` you have to explicitely convert it. This is mandatory in solidity to avoid mistakes, like the compiling making an erroneous conversion.